# how to install cordova plugin from a zip file

Tags: android, cordova, phonertc

I'm trying to install phoneRTC (https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc) but its taking forever with git clone:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc.git
```

That's why I decided to just use wget on the zip file available at github:

```
wget https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/archive/master.zip
```

Now I have the plugin on my computer. I tried extracting the zip file and putting it on the `plugins` directory of my project and renamed the folder to be the same as the `id` in the `config.xml` file:

```
com.dooble.phonertc
```

But when I tried building the apk file I got the following error:

```
/home/wern/www/chatapp/chatapp/platforms/android/src/com/dooble/phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.java:316: error: cannot find symbol
        webView.addView(_videoView, _videoParams);
               ^
  symbol:   method addView(VideoGLView,LayoutParams)
  location: variable webView of type CordovaWebView
/home/wern/www/chatapp/chatapp/platforms/android/src/com/dooble/phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.java:336: error: cannot find symbol
            webView.removeView(_videoView);
                   ^
  symbol:   method removeView(VideoGLView)
  location: variable webView of type CordovaWebView
/home/wern/www/chatapp/chatapp/platforms/android/src/com/dooble/phonertc/PhoneRTCPlugin.java:420: error: cannot find symbol
                        webView.removeView(_videoView);
                               ^
  symbol:   method removeView(VideoGLView)
  location: variable webView of type CordovaWebView
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Any ideas what's wrong? did I miss something? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncompress the plugin and install it like this:

```
cordova plugin add /path/to/the/uncompressed/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

I had solve this issue by Relplacing

`webView.addView(_videoView);`
 with

```
((WebView) webView.getView()).addView(_videoView);
```

and

`webView.addView(_videoView);`
   with

```
 ((WebView) webView.getView()).addView(_videoView);
```

I know this is an old question but hope will help someone.